# c++ Simple makefile advice

Tags: c++, makefile

Hello I am trying to create a very simple makefile. The makefile only includes one c file and two headers. When i compile using make I get: "Nothing to be done for 'makefile' ". The tutorials I am reading about makefiles do not have a lot of help when it comes to compilation errors.
Here is my makefile:

```
main_J: main_J.cpp functions_J.h head_struct.h
    g++ -o main_J main_J.cpp
```

Comment: Does `make main_J` work?

Comment: What is the exact command you use? What if you type `make main_J`?

Comment: Are you using a `tab` character to indent on the second line? Spaces won't work.

Comment: @Greg If that were the problem, he would not be getting that error message.

Comment: main_J does work, the command I used was "make makefile", I did use a tab

Comment: @josh Not your problem, but why give your make target and files such difficult names to type? Also, it is generally a bad idea to use mixed-case in source file names if you have any interest in portability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are doing

```
$ make makefile
```

This is attempting to **create** makefile. Instead you can do

```
$ make
```

This will execute the default rule, which is just the first one in your makefile. Alternatively, you can explicitly specify which target to build:

```
$ make main_J
```

Comment: Ok I tried the command "make" and the compiler said "main_J is up to date".

Comment: when i am using the command make, I am just compiling the file correct? would I still need to use ./a.out afterwards?

Comment: @JoshuaAyala then there are no changes since the last build. Run your program with `./main_J`. You can also make changes to your cpp file and run make again.

Comment: @JoshuaAyala it is also common to have a`clean` target which deleted all generated files.

Comment: Thank you for your input I really I appreciate it, it helped a lot! I wish I could have you around all of the time

Comment: @JoshuaAyala I am here regularly. Me and thousands of others.